# Using a CSS Selector to locate some data stored in a javascript element

Tags: javascript, css, perl, web-scraping, selector

I am doing some web scraping (with the ok of the site owner ) and have come across some data that is updated when a slider is moved.

Problem is that this data is inside some javascript.   I am using perl Web::Scraper which allows both CSS selectors and xpath selectors but I just can't seem to be able to isolate the javascript.

I have tried attribute selectors;  script[src="path_to.js"]  plain node selectors 'script' and the absolute css path - which just did not want to work at all.

Any ideas how to get to the content of a script node?

Answer (score 0):

Try [HTML::Query](http://search.cpan.org/~kamelkev/HTML-Query-0.08/lib/HTML/Query.pm)

```
use HTML::Query ();

# get raw (unparsed) content of page into $content.
# eg: $mech->content or similar
my $content = qq|
    <html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function init() {
                    var x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
                    alert(x);
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body onload="init()">
        </body>
    </html>
|;

# This is a CSS selector  ----------------------vvvvv
my ($e) = HTML::Query::Query(text => $content, 'script'); 
die "couldn't find script element!\n" unless defined $e;

# can't use as_text or as_trimmed_text from HTML::Element
print $e->as_XML."\n";
```

Comment: [Web::Query](http://p3rl.org/Web::Query) is better - CSS3 plus `:contains()`. HTML::Query only supports CSS 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [Mojo::DOM](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojo::DOM) example, where the `'text'` selects the bits that the tag contains:

```
use Mojo::DOM;

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( $content );

say $dom
    ->find( 'script' )
    ->map( 'text' )
    ->join( "\n" );
```

However, it sounds as if you might be trying to get something that the JavaScript does to the DOM, in which case Perl might not be able to see it.